# React Bootstrap Typeahead AsyncTypehead synchronous issue with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I am developing a user search feature in my react/redux application using **react-bootstrap-typehead**:  http://ericgio.github.io/react-bootstrap-typeahead/

The user search calls an API to search the list of users, so I am using the **AsyncTypeahead** component.

Since I are using Redux, I am storing the loading and search results within the store, so my code looks something like this:

```
const { searchPeople, loading, searchResults, selectedPerson } = this.props;
          <AsyncTypeahead
            isLoading={loading}
            options={searchResults}
            labelKey="DisplayName"
            clearButton
            minLength={5}
            onSearch={searchPeople}
            onChange={handleChange}
            placeholder="Search for a user..."
            renderMenuItemChildren={option => (
              <TypeaheadItem key={option.EmployeeID} item={option} {...this.props} />
            )}
          />
```

The `onSearch={searchPeople}` calls an action in Redux to call the API and store the results in "searchResults":

```
const searchPeople = term => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: REQUEST_SENT
  });

  const results = await dispatch(applicationActions.peopleSearch(term));

  dispatch({
    type: REQUEST_RECEIVED,
    data: results
  });
};
```

My "peopleSearch" function is stored in another action where I have all of our user search functionality.  That is why I am dispatching to another action.

```
const peopleSearch = searchTerm => async () => {
  const url = `https://api-personSearch.test.com/search=${searchTerm}&Output=JSONP`;
  const response = await fetchJsonp(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  return data.slice(0, 10);
};
```

Everything works perfectly if I search for a user typing slowly.  The problem is, if I type a users name quickly or at a normal pace, multiple "REQUEST_SENT" dispatches get called before any "REQUEST_RECEIVED" get called.  So looking at the Redux Dev Tools shows results looking like this:

```
REQUEST_SENT
REQUEST_SENT
REQUEST_SENT
REQUEST_RECEIVED
REQUEST_RECEIVED
REQUEST_RECEIVED
```

What ends up getting sent to the interface does not end up being the results for the last letter the user ended up typing.

What would be the proper way to use AsyncTypeahead with Redux so that the results are returned in the proper order that they are sent?

### Not Great Solution

One thing that ended up working (even though I think it's sort of a hack) is adding a "delay" to the AsyncTypehead.  Adding a `delay={1000}` prop to the AsyncTypeahead component gives the api just enough time to finish it's call before another call to the api is made.

I would like to find a better solution if one is possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "quickly or at a normal pace" vs. "slowly"? Note that `onSearch` should not fire until ${delay} ms after the user's last keystroke. If it's being triggered before then, it might be a problem with the typeahead's keystroke debouncing.

Comment: I'm referring to typing speed when I say quickly or slowly.  With a small ${delay} set, typing a name quickly is causing multiple requests to be sent and they finish in a different order then they are sent.  Forcing a delay of 1 second seems to do the trick, but I didn't know if that was the best solution.

Comment: There seem to be 2 potentially unrelated issues here: the first is `onSearch` firing too soon and the second is response order. For #1, can you confirm whether `onSearch` is firing before the delay is elapsed? Again, it should not fire until the specified delay *after* the last keystroke. For the second issue, you should note that response order is not guaranteed. Posting a working sandbox reproducing the issue might help debug.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a different issue in my usage, but I can suggest a solution to the ordering problem.

1. Store the last query string in Redux.
2. When a request completes, ignore it if it isn't for the last query string.

Ideally, you'd cancel the previous request when receiving a new one in `onSearch()`, but this will have the same effect. If the user keeps typing, delaying long enough for `onSearch()` to be fired but quick enough to cause overlapping requests, only the last request will display results.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug in the component where `AsyncContainer` and `TypeheadContainer` get out of sync. The delay approach works most of the time but even then I could type it in a way that I would get no results. Not happy with this answer either but turning off the cache is the only way to guarantee that doesn't happen.

```
useCache={false}
```